# including cordova.js exits my application

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, webview

when I include cordova-2.2..0.js in my phonegap application , it exits after a sec of loading index .html. though process keeps runing. just gui disappears ... have no clue how to approch the problem. works fine in emulator but crashes on actual device.

Answer (score 1):

1. First check that your **cordova.js** is loaded before **jquery.js** and **jquery_mobile.js**
2. If last point didn't help strip your code and make a basic page
3. If you still have a problem then your Cordova project has an error. Maybe a badly loaded plugin or you didn't set your project correctly (common problem).
4. If point 2. solved your problem check your js code, mainly parts using cordova/phonegap framework.
5. Have you used this line:

   ```
   navigator.app.exitApp();
   ```

   if answer is yes comment it and try again